# Detecting which key is pressed - is this a good way?

Tags: javascript, html, keystroke

I found a simple code on the internet a while ago... can't find the spesific site for it, but the code was made in 2005. So, I wondered if this was a good way of doing this:

This is in the HTML:

```
<body onload="document.body.focus();" onkeyup="return keypressed(event)">
```

When the key is up it calls this function in JavaScript:

```
function keypressed(e) {
    var intKey = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (intKey == 13) { // 13 = enter key
        //something happens if the key is clicked
    }
        // here, you can add as many if sentences for key strokes as you want! (same as first)

return true;
}
```

What I mean is that the code is 7 years old (maybe more!) and I thought it might be a little or very outdated!

My questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing this or is this still a good way? (I don't want to use jQuery for this code, because I don't want to use it just for one function)
2. Do I really need this code: `onload="document.body.focus();"`? (I have not programmed this code, so I don't know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `load` handler, the page will be already focused after it loads, and/or if someone presses *enter* anywhere on the page it will be focused too.

If you need the `keyup` handler depends on what you'd like to do with it. The code you show is an enter handler. If you want a text input field to act on typing *enter*, it's more efficient to add the handler to that field.

Furthermore, it's better to do that from within your scripting (a part of [unnobtrusive javascript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/unobtrusive-javascript/) usage). A `keypress` handler would be sufficient, because otherwise the *enter* value would become part of the input value. Something like:

```
[someTextInput].onkeypress = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  if ( (e.which || e.keyCode) === 13 ){
     // do things
  }
}
```

or you can use `addEventListener/attachEvent` ([See here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)).

Comment: @Kooilnc I am not exactly sure what you meant in your code... Can you please show me how to do it in practice?

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayunicode(e){
        var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode
        alert(unicode)
}
```

Another way to do the same thing.