# Modifying a link with user input

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a little chunk of code for a function, that I actually picked up in a different [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7097818/1646851), which was a huge help. Though, trying to modify that snippet of script has been giving me some trouble: I'm trying to change this bit so that instead of changing displayed text with a link, it will modify the link with either static text (like "Click here") or a button element.

```
<a id="reflectedlink" href="http://www.google.com/search">http://www.google.com/search</a>
<input id="searchterm"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var link= document.getElementById('reflectedlink');
   var input= document.getElementById('searchterm');
   input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() 
      {
         link.search= '?q='+encodeURIComponent(input.value);
         link.firstChild.data= link.href;     
      }; 
</script>
```

I would really like to have it a simple button that opens the modified link in a new window. I've tried looking for similar solutions and I'm sure I'm missing it just because I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. doesn't the link it displays already open a window when clicked?

Comment: To be more specific, I can put a static image in place of the text, but I'm trying to implement a button element. I know sometimes they fail to work in IE, but I'm not too well-acquainted with using forms just yet.

Comment: Josh -it does function, but I want to replace the text displaying the link with a button.

Comment: so you're looking at add a input button tag?

Comment: As long as that would still allow me to keep the rest of the script intact, I believe so. Again, I'm not sure what to call what I'm looking for, thus the trouble finding it.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to eliminate the link or box altogether, and just have it execute it from the user simply hitting "enter" and launching the link in a new window. But I don't even know where to begin asking that kind of function..

Comment: So the user will enter the query parameter and then when done hit enter which will open a new tab with the url and query parameter?

Comment: That would be ideal, because a streamlined input function like that would be best. Function is great, but I'm aiming for efficiency and ease-of-use. But, yes, Josh. Pretty much exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

[Modified your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/28/):

HTML

```html
Search <input id="searchterm" type="text" />
```

JavaScript

```js
var searchterm = document.getElementById('searchterm');
var base_url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=';
searchterm.onchange = searchterm.onkeyup = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    if ( (e.which || e.keyCode) == 13 ){
        window.open(base_url + encodeURIComponent(searchterm.value), '_blank');
    }
};
```

More info about the `window.open` function [is here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: That is a phenomenal help, thank you. Makes it much more streamlined than the clunky graphical button I had originally.

Comment: Thank you, just used here the answer from here: [Detecting which key is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549051/detecting-which-key-is-pressed-is-this-a-good-way/11549239#11549239) (it is compatible with IE8 and earlier versions)